# How to resize an image which has transparent portions in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, resize, uiimage

I am trying to resize a PNG which has transparent sections, first I used:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
[sourceImage  drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage* targetImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but the resultant image is opaque. Then I read that drawInRect by defaults draws the image as opaque, so I modified the drawInRect line to:

```
[fromImage  drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.0];
```

The resultant image is blank, I think there should be some combination of parameters in the drawInRect that will retain the transparency of the image.

I have searched other threads, and everywhere I see the generic resizing code, but nowhere it talks about images with transparent portions.

Anybody has any Idea ?

Answer (score -1):

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,newsize.width,newsize.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
[sourceImage drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
textureColor=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: I do not see anything different done here than what I have done. I did not want to save the image, so I do not need the last two lines anyway. I am using the resized image for masking, my problem is after getting the mage from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImagecontext() I am trying to use it for image masking and it appears that it is losing its transparency and it is treated as opaque square image.

Comment: Try this : UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);when we give scale=0,scalefactor set to device scale.